# Angular 2 Cli adding routes to existing project

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an existing Angular 2 App. Now I would like to use routing for navigation.
Is there a way to add routing to an existing Angular 2 Project using the Angular 2 Cli?

Lets say I have an Component "test" and want a route to this in a global Scope.

Comment: Oh, but they are proposing this, dont they? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-a-route

Comment: Ups this should be recent feature :)

Comment: huh, it seem only support when you create new module or new project, just create dump module then copy to your module, or create them manually

Comment: So I would create a new Module called "Routing"?

Comment: @MeMeMax i just checked link you send me it will initialize routing for new module, but still for components you will add routes manually.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the simplest way so far. I know this is already answered and accepted also but it is not working in the current scenarios because `ng init` is [removed](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/ed5f47dc22d5eb4a5d4b4ae2c8f7cb0ec1a999f3/CHANGELOG.md) so if you have forgotten to add routing while creating new project than you can add routes to existing project as following steps. Hope it will be helpful.

First of all add `app-routing.module.ts` file in your src --> app folder

**app-routing.module.ts** file would be like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';     // Add your component here
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';  // Add your component here

//This is my case 
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then **Import** `app-routing.module.ts` file in `app.module.ts` file as follow.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; // Added here
```

Now you will be able to perform routing task.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Things are changing over time so I will accept the best answer currently working.

Comment: Hope it will be helpful to others also

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Remember to add AppRoutingModule to the "imports" section of your @NgModule decorator in app.module.ts too.

Comment: Also add a <router-outlet>

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE** *Original question is about Angular 2 CLI. This doesn't work for curent Angular version!*

1. Run `ng init --routing`
2. And answer **no** every question from CLI.
   By this way you will get *app-routing.module.ts*.
3. Add `import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';`

and `imports: [AppRoutingModule]` to your *app.module.ts*

4. **Profit!** You get the same routing you would get if you would create routing with Angular CLI from the start.

Comment: Yes it works ood for a new project, but question is what to do in existing ?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat it's for existing project! Otherwise you wouldn't see prompts from the second paragraph.

Comment: But then I will have a own module for routing, right?

Comment: @MeMeMax yes, you will have _app-routing.module.ts_ file which will be imported in _app.module.ts_. If you start new project with routing you will have the same result.

Comment: @Lends - 

`ng init` was [removed as of 1.0.0-beta.32](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/ed5f47dc22d5eb4a5d4b4ae2c8f7cb0ec1a999f3/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic the question is about Angular 2, not about Angular 7.

Answer (score 8):

In Angular 5/6 you can use these commands to add routing to an existing project.

1. `ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app`

--flat puts the file in src/app instead of its own folder.
--module=app tells the CLI to register it in the imports array of the AppModule.

This will generate the file `src/app/app-routing.module.ts` for you.

2. Now inside `src/app/app-routing.module.ts` you have to import the router code:

   import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
3. Further, edit `src/app/app-routing.module.ts` to look like this:

```
    import { RouterModule, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import {class name} from 'address your component Component';
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '/home' , component : yourComponenetName}
    ];
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
      ],
      exports: [ RouterModule ]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

4. Next, add the `router-outlet` tag to your `app.html` file to tell the router where to display routed views.

```
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

5. Additionally, you should check in an `index.html` file with this tag at the top.

```
    <base href="/">
```

It will be added directly if you use the CLI command that I mention above.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** *Original question is about Angular 2 CLI. This doesn't work for curent Angular version!*

It depends but if you want to add routings to existing module then add folowing to your module.

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];
//in array you should have your routes like 
// { path: "path",  component: ComponentName },
```

Then in NgModule where you have `imports` definition

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

Or for child

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

Example for clean project

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';



const routes: Routes = [{ path: "path",  component: ComponentName }];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
```

Comment: Ok. But does it make sense to create a new Routing module to hold all the routes?

Comment: @MeMeMax No make no sense, new module is separation it make sence for instance if you have application with section like main site, admin panel, user orders etc, then each section will be new module.

Answer (score 1):

it is not explain if you currently has some router declared in your application, any way you can add routing in any moment.

It is not possible using the command --**ng int --routing** because was eliminated. and the routing option is only available when you running the new command, that create a new solution.

But you can create manually it. if you have some router in your app.module or none, you can follow the step described here to generate it:
[Implementing routing in separate module in angular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEB9RUCM1m8&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWUcq5Pc16uf8YKXoZ87Vh_&index=19)

Answer (score 0):

**update on the accepted answer**

make sure to follow below points:

**1>** 
make sure that `<base href="/">` is added inside index.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
```

**2>**
Add router outlet in ur app.component.html file  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

```
    div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
    Welcome to MyApp
    </h1>
    <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;....">
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

- router outlet tells the router where to display routed view.

**3>** Remember to add AppRoutingModule to the "imports" section of your @NgModule decorator in app.module.ts too

```
        @NgModule({
      imports: [
       AppRoutingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current (Angular 15) version of Angular, a project created with the angular routing configuration and one without, only differ in 4 files:

1. First there is an additional file in src/app called `app-routing.module.ts`, with the contents:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

2. `src/app/app.module.ts` has these two extra highlighted lines:

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
@NgModule({
    ...
  imports: [
    ...
    AppRoutingModule
```

[Image of diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEEMA.png)

3. `src/app/app.component.spec.ts` has these extra lines:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

   ...
   await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
```

[Image of diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGW5T.png)

4. `src/app/app.component.html` has an extra line at the very end of the file:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```